# Remove all Artist node from an XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XmlWriter that contains a xml that looks like the one below, just with a lot more nodes. what's the fastest and best way to remove all the ARTIST node from this xml ?

```
<CATALOG> 
  <CD> 
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE> 
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST> 
  </CD> 
  <CD> 
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE> 
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: Do you need to use the XmlWriter or can you use XmlDocument or XDocument?

Comment: I need to use XmlWriter. if there's a fast way to flip it to XmlDucument and flip back maybe it's fine enough.

Comment: XmlWriter cannot 'contain' XML - it can't read it or store it either.  How are you reading or storing the XML?  I would suggest using XSLT, by the way - use a default template to output everything other than artist.  The only reason I suggest is because that's what XSLT is for - transforming XML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the file isn't gigabytes XmlDocument should be fine:

```
    XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XDoc.Load(MapPath(@"~\xml\test.xml"));

    XmlNodeList Nodes = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ARTIST");

    foreach (XmlNode Node in Nodes)
        Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node);

    XDoc.Save(MapPath(@"~\xml\test_out.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2):

When I tried Steve's solution I received the following error "**The element list has changed. The enumeration operation failed to continue**". I know it is a bit of a hack but to get around this I used the following:

```
//Load XML
XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
XDoc.Load(MapPath(@"~\xml\test.xml"));

//Get list of offending nodes
XmlNodeList Nodes = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ARTIST");

//Loop through the list
while (Nodes.Count != 0) {
    foreach (XmlNode Node in Nodes) {
        //Remove the offending node
        Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node); //<--This line messes with our iteration and forces us to get a new list after each remove
        //Stop the loop
        break;
    }
    //Get a refreshed list of offending nodes
    Nodes = XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ARTIST");
}
//Save the document
XDoc.Save(newfile);
```

I was in a bind and needing something quick and this got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

From the way your question is worded, I'm assuming that you have an XmlWriter that has been used to write an XmlDocument and you want to manipulate what it is going to write before `flush` is called.

I'm afraid that what you're trying to do may be impossible. The XmlWriter is not meant to manipulate XML before it is written to a destination stream.

Comment: I don't mind to load it to xmldoucment and save it bacl after manipulation