# Remove nodes and child nodes from an XmlDocument Object based on attribute match

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have an xml file with Hierarchical data I am loading that into XmlDocument object all is well until now, what I want to do now is remove all nodes and child nodes except the one that have an attribute of

> AssetSysID="6288"

I am unsure of how to achieve this task any help is appreciated. Code for binding data to treeview:

```
 XmlDataSource xDS = new XmlDataSource();
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc = WTLIB.WTDAL.Legacy.DataTools.AssetList_XML(rcmbAssetType.SelectedValue);
                    if (xmlDoc != null)
                    {
                        #region Grid Filters
                if (Request.QueryString["grid"] == null)
                {
                    // Grid launched from Asset Screen
                    if (Request.QueryString["AssetSysID"] == null)
                        hdnGridAssetSysID.Value = "AssetSysID=" + "6288"; // Request.QueryString["AssetSysID"];
                    LoadGridData(xmlDoc);
                }

                #endregion

                xDS.Data = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
                xDS.XPath = "/xml/AMASM";
                xDS.EnableCaching = false;

                //  bind to treeview
                rtrvAMASM.Visible = true;
                rtrvAMASM.DataSource = xDS;
                rtrvAMASM.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                rtrvAMASM.Visible = false;
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            xDS = null;
            xmlDoc = null;
            rtrvAMASM.Visible = false;
        }
```

Xml:

```
<xml>
  <AMASM AssetSysID="6288" Asset_ID="786387126" FROMLR="0.0000" Assets="786387126,(Facilities) , ( to ) Big tower-to-,Facilities">
    <AMACI ACISysID="10201" PAssetSysID="6288" Features="Sign, On the door" />
    <AMACI ACISysID="10115" PAssetSysID="6288" Features="Roof, Roof, NE corner" />
    <WMITM ITMSysID="5267" Equipment="220033,Truck #33">
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="40" WorkOrders="E00006," />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="41" WorkOrders="E00007," />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="402" WorkOrders="E52,JDTest1" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="603" WorkOrders="E0130,Wash" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="656" WorkOrders="E0183,Program Error" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="712" WorkOrders="E0239,Program Error" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="986" WorkOrders="E0293,Testing Single Quote" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1534" WorkOrders="E0295," />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1548" WorkOrders="E0296,Testing Extra fields" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1589" WorkOrders="E0299,Testing Extra fields" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1590" WorkOrders="30-2,Testing Extra fields" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2179" WorkOrders="PW12-00011,OilChange2" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2299" WorkOrders="30-3,Testing Extra fields" />
      <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2310" WorkOrders="30-4,Testing Extra fields" />
    </WMITM>
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1534" WorkOrders="E0295," />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1548" WorkOrders="E0296,Testing Extra fields" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="656" WorkOrders="E0183,Program Error" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="712" WorkOrders="E0239,Program Error" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1589" WorkOrders="E0299,Testing Extra fields" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="1590" WorkOrders="30-2,Testing Extra fields" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2165" WorkOrders="A00506,Test Inser" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2166" WorkOrders="A00507," />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2167" WorkOrders="A00508,Test" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2299" WorkOrders="30-3,Testing Extra fields" />
    <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2310" WorkOrders="30-4,Testing Extra fields" />
    <AMFLI FLISysID="15" Floors="First Floor,Ground Level">
      <AMRMI RMISysID="21" Rooms="101,Admin Office">
        <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2165" WorkOrders="A00506,Test Inser" />
        <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2166" WorkOrders="A00507," />
        <AMSRQI SRQSysID="2167" WorkOrders="A00508,Test" />
      </AMRMI>
      <AMRMI RMISysID="22" Rooms="102,Security Office" />
      <AMRMI RMISysID="23" Rooms="103,Men's Washroom" />
      <AMRMI RMISysID="24" Rooms="104,Women's Washroom" />
    </AMFLI>
  </AMASM>
  <AMASM AssetSysID="6715" Asset_ID="HFBuild" FROMLR="0.0000" Assets="HFBuild,(Facilities) , High Falls Building,Facilities">
    <AMACI ACISysID="10132" PAssetSysID="6715" Features="" />
    <AMACI ACISysID="10133" PAssetSysID="6715" Features="" />
    <AMACI ACISysID="10134" PAssetSysID="6715" Features="" />
  </AMASM>
  <AMASM AssetSysID="6750" Asset_ID="F2000" FROMLR="0.0000" Assets="F2000,(Facilities) , Survey,Facilities" />
</xml>
```

Comment: Can you share your input xml? Is there any requirement about using XmlDocument, rather than say XDocument?

Comment: @Ryan: basically there is coding after that also(only some times this condition of certain assetsys id applies other times all xml data is needed using this on treeview) so because of that I don't want to touch the flow of the program or change the main object which is binding data to tree view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566228/remove-all-artist-node-from-an-xml-file):

```
 int intLoop = 0;
                    XmlNodeList Nodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AMASM");            
                    //  Loop through the list
                    while (Nodes.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode Node in Nodes)
                        {
                            if ( ! ( (Node.Attributes["AssetSysID"].Value) == hdnGridAssetSysID.Value) )
                            {
                                Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node); //   <--This line messes with our iteration and forces us to get a new list after each remove    
                                //  Stop the loop
                                break;
                            }                   
                        }
                        //  Get a refreshed list of offending nodes                
                        Nodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AMASM");
                        intLoop++;
                        if (intLoop > 5000) break;   // <-reason for that code is to break the loop out of infinity
                    }
                    Nodes = null;
                    intLoop = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");

doc.Root.Element("Applications").Elements("ApplicationName").Remove();

doc.Save("output.xml"); // or overwrite the input if wanted with doc.Save("input.xml");
```

Comment: using XmlDocument not xDocument, thanks for the reply @Shahrooz

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your xml, I would do the following:

```
XDocument.Load("input.xml").Descendants().Where(x => x.Attributes().Any(z => z.Name == "AssetSysID" && z.Value == "6288") == false);
```